# JSON Object from Glassfish via Rest Cannot resolve Polymoprh ObjectModel with Hashmap

Tags: java, json, rest, glassfish, polymorphism

First of all sorry for the complicated Title but I had no Idea how else I could name it.

I'm Trying to send a Object with a HashMap to a Client via Rest form a Glassfish server.

The Client recieves a JSON Object

```
/**
 * Testmethod
 *
 * @param id the identifier
 * @return a json object containing data of the tachoData object
 */
@POST
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TransferObject getTestHashMap(String id) {
    return controller.getTestHashMap(id);
}
```

So Far this works perfectly.

The TransferObject has the following Hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, ParentObject>
```

Now I want to put a extenden Object in the HashMap and send it to the Client.
I have a Child Object:

```
class ChildObject extends ParentObject{...}
```

And now I wanted to test what happens if i put the child-object in the HashMap and send it to the client.

```
PETransferObject r = new PETransferObject("Transfere");        
ChildObject o = ChildObject("Child001");
r.put("001TRansfer", o);
```

I filled the Objects with Dummy-Strings so JSON is not null.

---

So Far so good, now the Question:

IF the Map is defined like:

```
HashMap<String, ChildObject>
```

If works fine and a get the correct JSON object.

But If I want to use polymorphie it doesen't work.
Can someone tell we why and is there a workaround?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very descriptive.  What error / behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Oh okay, sorry.
By "It doesen't work" I mean, that the JSON object at the client doesn not contain any information that is extended by ChildObject.

Example: if the ChildObject wirtes in to an inherited Attribute, then the client will display the information. If the ChilObject writes into a own attribute, it will not show up in the JSON Object.